# Como buscar um determinado objeto dentro de um array?

Tags: javascript, indexof

Preciso saber se determinado `Array` possui um `objeto` com determinado valor em seu índice.

Tentei usar `indexOf`, porém não obtive êxito.

```
arr = [];

arr.push({id: 1, nome: 'Wallace'});

arr.indexOf({id: 1}); // -1
```

Como posso fazer pra realizar a busca desse objeto apenas pelo índice específico (nesse caso, o `id`)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Se você tiver uma referência do objeto, pode usar o `indexOf` mesmo, que faz busca por igualdade (duas referências só são iguais se apontarem para o mesmo objeto):

```
// Não se esqueça de usar var!
var arr = [];
var obj1 = {id: 1, nome: 'Wallace'}
arr.push(obj1);
arr.indexOf(obj1);
```

Caso contrário, precisa verificar tudo que existe no array, até achar seu objeto:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push({id: 1, nome: 'Wallace'});
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i].id === 1) {
        // achou!
    }
}
```

ou (IE9+):

```
var arr = [];
arr.push({id: 1, nome: 'Wallace'});
arr.forEach(function(el, i){
    if(el.id === 1) {
        // achou!
    }
});
```

ou ainda (IE9+):

```
var arr = [];
arr.push({id: 1, nome: 'Wallace'});
var existe = arr.some(function(el, i){
    return el.id === 1;
});
```

---

Esses são apenas alguns dos métodos possíveis. Nas outras respostas você verá que também dá pra fazer com [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), entre outros métodos.

Comment: _Não se esqueça de usar `var`_ me soou como uma mensagem subliminar

Comment: A ideia era essa mesmo :)

Answer (score 5):

Uma outra solução é usar o método `.map` (fonte:) https://stackoverflow.com/a/16008853/3956218)

O método `map()` invoca a função callback passada por argumento para cada elemento do `Array` e devolve um novo `Array` como resultado.

```js
var log = document.getElementById("menssagemLog");

arr = [];

arr.push({id: 1, nome: 'Wallace'});
arr.push({id: 2, nome: 'Carlos'});
arr.push({id: 3, nome: 'Livia'});

pos = arr.map(function(e) { return e.id; });
log.innerHTML += pos.indexOf(0)// Retorna -1
log.innerHTML += "<br/>"+pos.indexOf(1); // Retorna 0
log.innerHTML += "<br/>"+pos.indexOf(2); // Retorna 1
log.innerHTML += "<br/>"+pos.indexOf(4); // Retorna -1

console.log(log.innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="menssagemLog"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Porque não funcionou `arr.indexOf({id: 1});`?**

O problema é que quando fazes `arr.indexOf({id: 1});` estás a criar um novo objeto e não a criar um gémeo/igual do outro que já está dentro da array.

Repara que em JavaScript isto dá false:

```
var a = {id: 1};
var b = {id: 1};
a == b // false
```

Tens de usar algo que itere essa array. Por exemplo `.filter()`.

Em vêz de procurar por objeto sugiro usar uma array, ou dois parâmetros.
Algo assim:

```
function verificar(arr, procurar) {
    var chave = procurar[0];
    var valor = procurar[1];
    return !!arr.filter(function (el) {
        return el[chave] == valor;
    }).length;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o041a732/

Answer (score 3):

Olá,

Faria da seguinte maneira

```
function procurarIndice(arraySearch, atributo, valor){
   var cont=0;
   var indices=[];
   for(var i in arraySearch){
      var row = arraySearch[i];
      if(row[atributo]==valor){
         indices.push(cont)
      }
      cont++;
   }
   return indices;
}
arr = [];
arr.push({id: 1, nome: 'Wallace'});

procurarIndice(arr,"id",1);
```

A função retornaria um array de índices, e para validar se o valor esperado existe, poderia usar um if pela quantidade

```
if(procurarIndice(arr,"id",1).length>0){
   ...
}
```

Comment: +1. Isso gera a possibilidade de passar um array no terceiro parâmetro

Answer (score 1):

O método `indexOf` (assim como o `includes`) funciona com base num algoritmo de comparação similar ao utilizado pelo `===`.

Desse modo, dois objetos criados que não tiverem a mesma referência, mesmo que tenham estruturas iguais, serão considerados diferentes. Isso significa que você não pode utilizar métodos como `indexOf` ou `includes` para verificar se um determinado objeto existe dentro de um array. Eles simplesmente não funcional para o tipo de comparação estrutural que geralmente se faz necessária ao comparar objetos.

Nesse tipo de caso, o JavaScript não tem como prever *como* você deseja comparar dois objetos, afinal, se não é por referência, é pelo quê? Duas propriedades `id` iguais (como no caso desta pergunta)? Ou todas as outras propriedades iguais? Quem determina isso é você.

O JavaScript provê, no protótipo de arrays, dois métodos, `find` e `findIndex` que, através de um *callback*, permitem comparações mais complexas a cada elemento do array. Então podemos utilizá-los.

O método `find` irá executar o algoritmo de comparação especificado dentro do *callback* para cada elemento do array e retornará o *primeiro* elemento que faça o *callback* retornar `true`. Do contrário, retorna `undefined`.

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Foo' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bar' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Baz' }
];

const needle = arr.find((currObj) => {
  // Note que o callback retornará `true` se o objeto
  // atual tiver propriedade `id` igual a 2.
  return currObj.id === 2
});

console.log(needle); // { id: 2, name: 'Bar' }
```

E também (mais no sentido esperado pela pergunta) existe o `findIndex`, que funciona similarmente ao `find`, só que retorna o índice. No caso de não encontrar, retorna -1. Exemplo:

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Foo' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bar' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Baz' }
];

const needleIndex = arr.findIndex((currObj) => {
  // Note que o callback retornará `true` se o objeto
  // atual tiver propriedade `id` igual a 2.
  return currObj.id === 2
});

console.log(needleIndex); // 1
```

Claro que dá para utilizar um `for` e fazer isso na mão, mas esses métodos são bem convenientes nesse caso (e têm a mesma complexidade assintótica). Você pode utilizar o `filter` se quiser encontrar mais de um elemento do array que passe ao predicado fornecido. O `find`, assim como `findIndex`, retorna somente o primeiro elemento encontrado de acordo com a comparação especificada.

Não sugiro utilizar `map` e posteriormente `indexOf` já que isso percorreria o array duas vezes. Claro que continua sendo linear, mas me parece um desperdício. O `findIndex` pode, se utilizar a notação curta de *arrow functions*, ser bastante expressivo:

```
arr.findIndex((obj) => obj.id === 2);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var arr = [{id:1, desc:"1111"},{id:2, desc:"222"},{id:3, desc:"3333"},{id:4, desc:"4444"}];

arr.filter(function( obj ) {
  return obj.id == 1;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var id = 1;
var dados = [{id: 1, nome: 'Wallace'},{id: 2, nome: 'Wall'}];  

var i = dados.indexOf(dados.filter((item) =>  item.id == id)[0],0);
console.log(i);
```