# Buscar elementos array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Gostaria de criar um `input` que receba um valor informado pelo usuário e que ao clicar em um botão ele executasse uma função que verifica se o valor inserido existe no meu array e se existe qual índice está contido.

```
var vetor = [1, 2, 3];<br>
var elemento = document.getElementById("verifica").value;

<.input type='text' id="verifica">
```

Comment: [**Como buscar um determinado objeto dentro de um array?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77622)

Comment: O que são esses `<br>` perdidos no meio de javascript ? Tente formular melhor a sua pergunta, se possível com exemplos mais concretos.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer dessa forma:
O método `indexOf` procura o valor (`val`) no vetor (`vetor`) se encontrar ele retorna a posição do elemento no array.
Se caso ele não encontrar o valor ele retorna -1.
Um array começa na posição 0. Fiz uma soma no resultado para aumentar em uma casa as posições.  Assim então as posições serão maiores que zero.
 É importante observar a função `parseInt()` ela transforma em inteiro o que é passado como parâmetro. Que é útil nesse exemplo pois queremos realizar comparações e operações entre inteiros.

```js
var verifica = function(){
    var vetor = [1, 2, 3];
    var val = document.getElementById("verifica").value;
   
    var a = vetor.indexOf(parseInt(val));

    if(a === -1){

      alert("Valor não encontrado")

    }else if(a !== -1){

      alert("Valor encontrado na posição " + (a+1));

    }

  }
```

```html
 <input id="verifica" type="text" >
  <button type="submit" onclick="verifica()">Verificar
  </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use um loop para iterar os elementos do Array e se algum valor corresponder ao valor do input retorne o índice desse elemento.

```js
    var vetor = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    function checar(){
      valInput=document.getElementById("verifica").value;
      for (var i = 0; i < vetor.length; ++i) {
          if (vetor[i] == valInput) {
              index = i;
              console.log(index);
              break;
          }
      }
    }
```

```html
    <input id="verifica" type="text">
    <button type="submit" onclick="checar()">Verificar</button>
```

> Pode usar [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), porém não funciona no IE 11 e anteriores

Comment: Negativar é facil, apenas um clique, difícil é postar uma resposta melhor para depois se sentir a vontade para negativar as outras. Na terra dos gringos esse script obteve 32 ups. Enfim aqui terra Brasilis as coisas são diferentes.

Comment: Infelizmente algo está acontecendo, todas as soluções propostas foram votadas negativamente.Talvez não tenha testado nenhuma das soluções proposta aqui. E esteja apenas votando negativamente todas as respostas. Talvez a pergunta deva ser excluida.

Comment: @Felipe Infelizmente, aqui tem gente que fica olhando defeito nos scripts dos outros mas não apresenta solução/sugestão/critica construtiva alguma.

Comment: é .. eu também tive  a minha negativada. Mas com razão. Escrevi um texto fraco e um código com um erro na estrutura condicional. Hoje de manhã percebi o erro na resposta e a editei. Sinto que isso é ruim mesmo. Tem gente que desqualifica qualquer pergunta quanto mais as respostas. Ego inflamando é o nome disso.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75640/votos-negativos-sem-explicacao